# Android stream multiple bitmap tiles to single jpeg file

Tags: android, image-manipulation, jpeg

I am developing an image manipulation application which has to be able to work on large images e.g. those taken by a camera, the approach I'm taking is to split the source image into multiple suitably sized tiles so that the tiles can be loaded individually into memory as a Bitmap without exceeding the dreaded VM limit, next image manipulation is performed on a tile by tile basis, this is all well and good but until I want to stitch these tiles back to a final jpeg image.
I'm looking for a built in sdk api or free ware solution that can perform the following:

Open jpeg output file as output stream

Stream RGB pixels from bitmap (tile 1) to jpeg output stream

Stream RGB pixels from bitmap (tile 2) to jpeg output stream

etc.. for all tiles

Close jpeg output stream

Any ideas or pointers other than writing my own jpeg encoder?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you slice the images in the beginning?

Comment: I use BitmapRegionDecoder with a Rect indicating the region of the source (big bitmap/jpeg) that I want to grab, e.g. if my source image is 2000x2000 pixels and I want 4 tiles the first tile would be (0,0)-(1000,1000), second would be (1000,0)-(2000,1000), third (0,1000)-(1000,2000) and fourth (1000,1000)-(2000,2000). I process these one by one and save off to temporary bitmaps on the sdcard, the problem is then stitching these back to form a final image (preferably a jpeg).

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(output_file);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outFile);
outFile.flush();
outFile.close();
```

You can adjust the quality setting (100). See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29)

You'll still need to decide how to slice it. But if you're taking the image on the device, why would it be a problem loading the whole image if it didn't cause a memory problem in the first place?

**Stitching Tiles back together**: Here's one simple approach used by slippy maps the I know works.

1. Cut tiles in standard size (say 256x256)
2. Assign each tile an x,y value - this could be a directory structure or filename convention: i.e. "0_0.jpg"
3. Tile names (numbers) are related to their top/left pixel position.

Each tile number can be calculated by the following:

`tileX = floor(pixelX / 256)`

`tileY = floor(pixelY / 256)`

So the tile at pixels 0,0 = tile (0,0), the tile at pixels 256,0  is tile (1,0), etc...

Comment: That would do a single bitmap but if I wanted to join/stitch 2 (or more) bitmaps how would this work, there is JPEG header and footer data around the core JPEG image data, the FileOutputStream would create the initial stream but how would the bitmap.compress method know I will be passing a second (or further) bitmap, could I call bitmap1.compress(...) and then bitmap2.compress(...) and the resulting file would be a jpeg containing both bitmaps joined together (and if so would these be vertically joined)?

Comment: Are you asking how you would join the jpeg images back together on screen?

Comment: The memory problem comes from the fact that most modern phones can take high resolution images e.g. via an 8megapixel camera, the camera writes the image to the sdcard as a compressed file e.g. jpeg but then loading this in as a bitmap results in a much bigger i.e. decompressed image which typically exceeds the 16MB VM limit (or less on phones with less memory), therefore you have to be very cunning when trying to perform image manipulation on potentially massive bitmaps, hence tiling and splitting up the work on smaller pieces.

Comment: The app I'm working on is to perform red-eye removal on photographs, I can perform the UI elements of the user tapping where the red eyes are and then performing red eye removal on a sampled image (again to be able to preview the image without exceeding memory limitations). I then save the coordinates where they've tapped and when they click apply I need to replay the red eye removal on the real unsampled i.e. large image.

Comment: You can potential use an approach similar to how slippy maps work to stich the tile back together.  Assuming you are somehow cutting the tiles you could load them as one by assigning each tile an X,Y value that corresponds to pixel position this would stich the tiles into what appears to be a single image.  Does that make sense? If so I can provide so additional information that may be helpful

Comment: Sounds interesting yes please, its the stitching back without needing to have all the source tiles and the destination image in memory. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks but how are the 0_0.jpg 1_0.jpg etc. individual files joined back to a final combined image?

Comment: In on onDraw() of your view, loop over and load each tile needed from file: Bitmap b1 = load(0_0.jpg) ....  then draw them with canvas.drawBitmap(b1,0,0), canvas.drawBitmap(b2, 256,0), etc...

Comment: That approach requires the final bitmap to be in memory which will cause out of memory exceptions for large Bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

Your stitching approach has two major issues and will ultimately fail. If you ask the system to decode a JPEG file in parts, the decode time will end up being close to N times longer (N = number of parts). The next problem is that when trying to save the image you will run out of memory. JPEG images need to be compressed in one shot. If your entire uncompressed image can't fit in memory, then you won't be able to use the technique you're using.

The hard truth is that, with Android as it is currently designed, you must use native code to hold on to the bitmap in order to manage an image larger than the VM memory limit. It's not that difficult, but it does require a re-design of your app.

Comment: Thanks BitBank,  I considered native code but I'm relatively new developing on Android, I thought you could encoded a jpeg serially, jpeg works on 8x8 tiles as I understand it and then compresses so it still sounds like it could work but I take your point on the performance.

Comment: JPEG is essentially built from 8x8 blocks, but normal JPEG encoders don't allow you to build a file piecemeal. You would need to write your own JPEG encoder and it would still require all of the horizontal pieces to be in memory at once. You would need to divide your image into short horizontal stripes in order to incrementally encode it.