# How to create a huge size of jpeg in android app?

Tags: android, jpeg

I am now thinking about how large resolution jpeg can android support, with format config rgb? So far as I know, bitmap can support up to size 4G, and the maximum width and height are both 32k, but restrict to app memory, obviously, we cannot do this.

So，here is the question,
if we have 25 pic of 4K * 4K rgb jpeg,
can we create a jpeg that tile all these difference pic together, in sorted order of top to down？

ref link：[Android stream multiple bitmap tiles to single jpeg file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507595/android-stream-multiple-bitmap-tiles-to-single-jpeg-file)

Comment: If you simply want to *create* (not displaying), jpegtran (already ported to Android) can stitch JPEGs without decoding, so even low-end phones can do that efficiently. Displaying it will require a combination of multiple resolution thumbnails and dynamic painting, similar to how Google Earth works.

Comment: Thx, I will have a try, would you please give me more details if you don't mind.